# How do I work with a SAS file that was created in a different format (Linux/Windows) if I don't have access to machine that created it?

Tags: sas

I have numerous SAS datasets on my Windows 7 / SAS 9.4 machine:

```
data_19921.sas7bdat
data_19922.sas7bdat
data_19923.sas7bdat
....
data_200212.sas7bdat
```

etc. The format is `data_YYYYM.sas7bdat` or `data_YYYYMM.sas7bdat` (the latter for two digit months) and every dataset has identical variables and formatting. I'm trying to iterate over all of these files and append them into one big SAS dataset. The datasets were created on some Unix machine elsewhere in my company that I don't have access to. When I try to append the files:

```
%let root = C:\data;

libname in "&raw\in";
libname out "&raw\out";


/*****************************************************************************/

* initialize final data set but don't add any observations to it;
data out.alldata;
    set in.data_19921;
    stop;
run;

%macro append_files;
%do year=1992 %to 2002;
    %do month=1 %to 12;
        proc append data=out.alldata base=in.data_&year&month;
        run;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;

%append_files;
```

I get errors that say

> File in.data_19921  cannot be updated because its encoding does not match the session encoding or the file is in a format native to another host, such as LINUX_32, INTEL_ABI

I don't have access to the Unix machine that created these datasets (or any Unix machine right now), so I don't think I can use [`proc cport` and `proc cimport`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/cport-overview.htm).

How can I read/append these data sets on my Windows machine?

Comment: Usually CEDA takes care of that and simply puts a warning to the log, but still proceeds. What version of SAS are you on?

Comment: @Reese I'm using SAS 9.4 on Windows 7 (see my first sentence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the colon operator or dash to shortcut your process:

```
data out.alldata;
    set in.data_:;
run;
```

OR

```
data out.alldata;
    set in.data19921-in.data200212;
run;
```

If you have variables that are different lengths you may get truncation. SAS will warn you though:
WARNING: Multiple lengths were specified for the variable name by input data set(s). This may
         cause truncation of data.

One way to avoid it is to create a false table first, using the original table. The following SQL code will generate the CREATE Table statements and you can modify the lengths manually as needed.

```
proc sql;
      describe table in.data19921;
quit;

*run create table statement here with modified lengths;

data out.alldata;
    set fake_data (obs=0)
       in.data19921-in.data200212;
run;
```

Comment: You have got to be kidding me. This is brilliant, and I think it's exactly what I need. Will this truncate any data, e.g. if one dataset has the variable `x` that's a str2 variable, while another dataset's `x` is a str3 variable? I'm used to Stata, where it automatically expands the datatype without truncation.

Comment: You can get truncation. I'll modify the answer to show a way to avoid that, which is really only feasible if you don't have a ton of variables.

Comment: You could also use the sashelp.vcolumn view to look at each variable in those tables, getting the max length.  From that, a macro to create the `fake_data` table would be pretty easy (and a good follow up question).